# How can we setup storybook in our systems without errors

Tags: storybook

I am facing an error when trying to install storybook. I tried by re-installing node.js but i am facing the same issue. How can we resolve this type of issues.

C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules@storybook\cli\bin\index.js:23
throw error;
^

InvalidArgumentError: invalid url
at Object.parseOrigin (C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:1:17776)
at new Pool (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:47:6390)
at defaultFactory (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:47:42495)
at new ProxyAgent (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:47:43707)
at new UndiciProxyAgent (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:61:1383)
at createProxy (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:61:3071)
at createFetch (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:61:3218)
at Object. (C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\node-fetch-native\dist\proxy.cjs:61:3353)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1375:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:10) {
code: 'UND_ERR_INVALID_ARG'
}

Node.js v21.5.0

I tried by re-installing the node.js as I thought it was occuring due to node.js
But the eror hasnt resolved.
How can we resolve these kind of issues and why we are getting these issues.